# Explain why the function $ \ f: [-\pi, \pi] \times [-\pi,\pi] \to \mathbb{R}^3 \ $ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Explain why the function $ \ f: [-\pi, \pi] \times [-\pi,\pi] \to \mathbb{R}^3 \ $ defined by $ \ f(u,v)=((\cos u+2) \cos v, (\cos u+2) \sin v, \sin u ) \ $  is continuous.

Also find the range of $ \ f \ $ .

**Answer:**

$ \ f(u,v)=((\cos u+2) \cos v, (\cos u+2) \sin v, \sin u ) \ $  is continuous because each of its components functions $ \ (\cos u+2) \cos v , \ \ (\cos u+2) \sin v, \ \ \sin v \ $ are continuous on the domain $ [-\pi, \pi] \times [-\pi,\pi] $

But what are its range in $ \ \mathbb{R}^3 \ $ ?

**Help me out**

Comment: Your u's and v's should be x's and y's (or vice versa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $[\cos(u)+2, \sin(u)]$ describes a circle centred at ...

And then you rotate ...

Comment: I did not get you. How to find the range of the function ?

Comment: I think the function $ \ F \ $ maps on a sphere

Comment: @yourmath As Robert Israel suggested, draw circles when $v=0,\pm\pi/2,\pi$, and then rotate the circles around the $z$-axis. Then you can imagine the result, one of beautiful surfaces.